# React Native map with Google API, Search bar is not compactable with screen width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the code for React Native Map using Google Map's API.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PermissionsAndroid, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const GOOGLE_API_KEY = *GOOGLE API*
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

function App() {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState({ latitude: 0, longitude: 0 })

  async function getPermission() {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    )
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getPermission().then(() => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          setLocation({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
          })
        },
        (error) => {
          // See error code charts below.
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000 }
      );
    })

  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        region={{
          latitude: 38.695794,
          longitude: -101.807704,
          // latitude: location.latitude,
          // longitude: location.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}>
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: 38.695794,
            longitude: -101.807704,
          }}
        />
      </MapView>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      style={styles.searchBar}
      placeholder='Search Places'
      query={{
        key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        language:'en'
      }}
      GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
        fields:'geometry'
      }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#369',
    paddingTop:5
  },
  map:{
    left:0,
    right:0,
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    position:'absolute'
  },
  searchBar:{
    description:{
      fontWeight:"bold"
    },
    predefinedPlacesDescription:{
      color:"red"
    },
    textInputContainer:{
      backgroundColor:'#369',
      top:50,
      width:screenWidth - 20,
      borderWidth:0
    },
    textInput:{
      marginLeft:0,
      marginRight:0,
      height:38,
      color:'#5d5d5d',
      fontSize:16,
      borderWidth:0
    },
    listView:{
      backgroundColor:'rgba(192,192,192,0.9)',
      top:23
    }
  }
})

export default App
```

[image: The Search bar is shown too small. Why? And the Styles are not applying]

The place search bar is too small. But it's still working. When clicking the search bar the width of the search bar is equal to the screen width. The issue is solved when removing Container Style `alignItems:'center'`.

The Styles are also not applying for the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place search bar is too small. But it's still working. When clicking the search bar the width of the search bar is equal to the screen width. The issue is solved when removing Container Style `alignItems:'center'`

The Styles are also not applied to the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried add view outside the search component?

maybe like below

```
<View
   style={{
       position: "absolute",
       zIndex: 1,
       width: deviceWidth || "100%" || "custom width value" // with width
   }}>

   <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
     style={styles.searchBar}
     placeholder='Search Places'
     query={{
       key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
       language:'en'
     }}
     GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{
       fields:'geometry'
     }}
     />

</View>
```